Not able to add new empty lines in the about tab
Microsoft Teams custom app about tab adding a new empty lines using \n is not appearing on the Teams about tab, even some of text formatting is not available, does text formatting is not supported on the custom app about tab.

The Microsoft Teams custom app about tab supports text formatting using Markdown and adding new lines using the escape sequence
\n.
You can use Markdown to format the text in the about tab of your custom app. However, please note that the formatting support may vary between different card types and the rendering may differ slightly between the desktop and mobile versions of Teams.
Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cconnector-html
